# HERE API modify geojson markers on event

Tags: here-api

I have a lot of markers loaded onto my map via the geojson reader. It runs just fine when its zoomed to at around 1-2 blocks, but when i zoom out my app slows down significantly because there are so many icons shown on the map. I'd like to have my map hide (or remove?) all of the markers when I zoom out to certain level, and show back up when zoomed back in at a certain level.

I've figured out how to add a zoom event and track the zoom level, but I am completely lost when it comes to modifying the style of the reader layer on that event, or how I'd dynamically remove and add markers without bogging the whole app down.

```
var icon = new H.map.Icon('icon_image.png');

// read in the geojson data and set the icon image for markers
reader = new H.data.geojson.Reader("test.geojson",{
    style: function(mapObject){
        if (mapObject instanceof H.map.Marker){
          mapObject.setIcon(icon)
        }
      }
});

// add geojson layer to map
reader.parse();
map.addLayer(reader.getLayer());

// add an event to listen when zoom event
map.addEventListener("mapviewchangeend",function(){
    if (map.getZoom() < 10){
        // DONT SHOW (OR REMOVE) MARKERS
    } 
    if (map.getZoom() >= 10) {
        // SHOW (OR ADD) MARKERS
    }
})
```